Show there is no positive r.v. $U$ such that $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[U^k 1_{U \ge (k+1)/2 }]}{\mathbb{E}[U^k]}, \, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0$
Let $U$ be a non-negative random variable such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} =  \frac{\mathbb{E}[U^k 1_{U \ge  \frac{k+1}{2}   }]}{\mathbb{E}[U^k]}.    
\end{align}
In the above, we use the convention that $0^0=1$.  We also assume that $U$ has all finite moments for the problem to be well-defined.
Question Can we show that there exists no random variable $U$ such that the above is true?
My first attempt was to study the limit:
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[U^k 1_{U \ge   \frac{k+1}{2}   }]}{\mathbb{E}[U^k]},
\end{align}
and show that there is no $U$ such that this limit is equal to $1/2$. However, it turns out that the gamma random variable with parameters $(1,1)$ satisfies this. So one cannot just consider large $k$ values the small $k$ values also have to play a role.
My second approach was to considered an approach of writing $\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[U^k] =  \mathbb{E}[U^k 1_{U \ge  \frac{k+1}{2}   }]$ . I was hoping to transform this equality to a different domain. For example, by using $z$-transform move it to 'frequency' domain.  However, that didn't really work due to technical issue with domain of convergence of $z$-transform.
This is somewhat reminiscent of the moment problem.  This problem came up in the context of estimation theory where this moment problem comes up in the middle of proof for consistency of an estimator.
Edit: One of the comments suggest that it would be interesting to study a more relaxed problem. Give $M$, does there exists $U_M$ such that the equality is true for $ k \le M$?  I agree that this is an interesting problem especially for $M >2$.
Edit 2:  A more relaxed problem has been solved (See below). It was shown that for every $M \ge 2$ there exists a solution.

What's the context in which the problem arose? Is there more info that might help potential answerers? (Just as a suggestion on style: it is better to not write your question titles in the imperative tense, i.e. as a command - it looks like an assignment question to my eyes. Also, putting the entire problem in the title is unnecessary, just put something descriptive of the general type of problem it is)

@DavidRoberts Thanks for the suggestion. Let me add these details.

It is not 100% clear to me, do you mean that it holds for all $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$?

@AlekseiKulikov Yes, the ratio is constant for all $k$. Let me update it.

In addition to @DavidRoberts's suggestions, I believe that general etiquette frowns on putting titles in display mode. I edited to inline mode.

@LSpice Will do. Thanks

Do you know the answer to a more relaxed version: is it true that for each $M$ there exists a non-negative random variable $U_M$ such that $E[U_M^k 1_{U_M\geq(k+1)/2}]/E[U_M^k]=1/2$ for all integers $k$ such that $0 \leq k \leq M$?

@ssssnnnn  Good question. Unfortunately, I do not know if there is solution. I tried setting up a system of equations, and tried arguing that it would have a solution, but it's not very clean.  Do you have any ideas?

I think, my answer also solves the original problem too (I showed how to deduce the existence of U from the existence of U_M)

@ssssnnnn Thank you! I am going over your proof. I hope you don't mind if I ask you questions.

For every $M \geq 1$ and every finite sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{M+1}$, where $x_k \in [(k-1)/2,k/2)$, there exists $U_M$ whose distribution has support $\{x_1,\dots,x_{M+1}\}$ such that the inequality is true for $k \leq M-1$ (the proof is below).
The existence of such $U_M$ implies that for an infinite sequence $x_1,x_2\dots$ such that $x_k \in [(k-1)/2,k/2)$ there exists $U$ which takes values in $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ for which the desired equalities hold. Indeed, for each $M$ construct $U_M$ corresponding to $\{x_1,\dots,x_{M+1}\}$. Denote $p_{M,k}=\mathbb{P}\{U_M=k\}$.
Remark that for $l \geq 2k+3$ we have $x_l \geq k+1$, so for each $M \geq k+1$ we have $$\mathbb{P}\{U_M \geq x_{l}\}\leq E[U_M^k \mathbf{1}_{U_M \geq (k+1)}(k+1)^{-k}]
\leq E[U_M^k \mathbf{1}_{U_M \geq (k+1)/2}(k+1)^{-k}]=E[U_M^k \mathbf{1}_{U_M < (k+1)/2}(k+1)^{-k}] \leq 2^{-k}.$$
By passing to a subsequence (diagonal argument) we can assume that for each $k \geq 1$ there exists a limit $\lim_{M \to \infty} p_{M,k}=p_k$: indeed, since $p_{M,0} \in [0,1]$ for each $M$, there exists an infinite increasing sequence $(M_{0,i})_{i \geq 0}$ such that for some real number $p_0$ we have $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_i,0}=p_0$. Out of $(M_{0,i})_{i \geq 0}$ we can pick an increasing infinite subsequence $(M_{1,i})_{i \geq 0}$ such that $M_{1,i}>M_{0,i}$ for each $i$ and in addition both $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_{1,i},0}=p_0$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_{1,i},1}=p_1$ for some $p_1 \in [0,1]$. Out of $(M_{1,i})_{i \geq 0}$ we can pick an increasing infinite subsequence $(M_{2,i})_{i \geq 0}$ such that $M_{2,i}>M_{1,i}$ for each $i$ and in addition $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_{2,i},0}=p_0$,
$\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_{2,i},1}=p_1$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty} p_{M_{2,i},2}=p_2$ and so on. Then we will have $\lim_{j \to \infty} p_{M_{j,j},k}=p_k$ for each $k$, because for $i \geq k$ the number $M_{i,i}$ belongs to the sequence $(M_{k,j})_{j \geq 0}$, and $M_{i,i} > M_{i-1,i}>M_{i-1,i-1}$ for $i \geq 1$.
Then $0 \leq p_k \leq 1$, and $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k = \sup_{N \geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^{N} p_k = \sup_{N \geq 1}\lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N} p_{M,k}\leq \sup_{N \geq 1}\lim_{M \to \infty} 1 = 1.$$
However, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i \geq 1$, because for each $k > 0$ we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2k+2} p_i=\lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{2k+2} p_{M,i}=\lim_{M \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\{U_M \leq x_{2k+2}\}=1-\lim_{M \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\{U_M > x_{2k+2}\}=
1-\lim_{M \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\{U_M \geq x_{2k+3}\}\geq 1-2^{-k}$$ (since $\mathbb{P}\{U_M \geq x_{2k+3}\} \leq 2^{-k}\}$ for $M \geq k$ as shown before).
Therefore, there exists a random variable $U$ supported on $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ such that $\mathbb{P}\{U=x_k\}=p_k$ for each $k$. It remains to prove that for $k \geq 0$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} p_i x_i^k = \sum_{i=k+2}^{\infty} p_i x_i^k,$$ in particular, that the right-hand side converges. Remark that
$$\sum_{i=k+2}^{\infty} p_i x_i^k
=\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=k+2}^{N} p_i x_i^k
=\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=k+2}^{N} p_{M,i} x_i^k
=\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=k+2}^{\infty} p_{M,i} x_i^k
-\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_{M,i} x_i^k
=\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} p_{M,i} x_i^k
-\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_{M,i} x_i^k
=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} p_i x_i^k
-\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_{M,i} x_i^k.
$$
From the above we know that for all $l$, for all $M \geq l+1, i \geq 2l+3$ we have $p_{M,i} \leq 2^{-l}$. Hence, for all $l \geq 4$ and $M \geq l+1$ we have $p_{M,l}\leq 2^{-l/2+2}$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_{M,i} x_i^k
\leq 
\limsup_{N \to \infty} \limsup_{M \to \infty} \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} p_{M,i} 
x_i^k
\leq
\limsup_{N \to \infty}
\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} 2^{-i/2+2} 
(i/2)^k = 0,
$$
so $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} p_i x_i^k = \sum_{i=k+2}^{\infty} p_i x_i^k$$ as desired.
The shorter proof of the existence of such $U_M$
It is enough to prove that for each $M \geq 1$ and $0<x_1<\dots<x_{M+1}$ there exist $(p_1,\dots,p_{M+1})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{M+1} p_k=1$ and for $0 \leq k \leq M-1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} p_i x_i^k =\sum_{i=k+2}^{M+1} p_i x_i^k$. Proceed by induction in $M$. The basis $M=1$ is easy. Assume that for $M$ the statement is proven. Let $x_{M+2}>x_{M+1}$. By the induction assumption for $M$ and $(x_0,\dots,x_M,x_{M+2})$ there exist $(q_1,\dots,q_{M+1})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{M+1} q_k=1$ and for $0 \leq k \leq M-1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} q_i x_i^k =\sum_{i=k+2}^{M} q_i x_i^k+q_{M+1} x_{M+2}^k$. Then for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $(r_1,\dots,r_{M+2})=\lambda(p_1,\dots,p_M,p_{M+1},0)+(1-\lambda)(q_1,\dots,q_M,0,q_{M+2})$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{M+2} r_k=1$, and $0 \leq k \leq M-1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} r_i x_i^k =\sum_{i=k+2}^{M+2} r_i x_i^k$. It remains to choose $\lambda \in [0,1]$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{M+1} r_i x_i^M = r_{M+2} x_{M+2}^k$, that is,
$$\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{M+1} p_i x_i^M + (1-\lambda) \sum_{i=1}^{M} q_i x_i^M = (1-\lambda)q_{M+1} x_{M+2}^M.$$ It is always possible, since for $\lambda=1$ the left-hand side is bigger than the right-hand side, while for $\lambda = 0$ the right-hand side is bigger than the right-hand side as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{M} q_i x_i^M < x_{M+2} (\sum_{i=1}^{M} q_i x_i^{M-1}) = x_{M+2}(q_{M+1} x_{M+2}^{M-1})=q_{M+1} x_{M+2}^M.
$$
The longer proof of the existence of such $U_M$
Consider a slightly modified "signed Vandermonde" matrix $A$ of size $(M+1)\times(M+1)$, namely, a matrix such that $a_{ij}=\epsilon_{ij}x_j^{i-2}$ for $2 \leq i \leq M+1,\,1 \leq j \leq M+1$ and $a_{1j}=1$ for $1 \leq j \leq M+1$, where $\epsilon_{ij}=1$, if $j \geq i$ and $\epsilon_{ij}=-1$, if $j < i$.
It is enough to prove that the equation $A \cdot p=(1,0,\dots,0)^{\top}$ ($p$ and $(1,0,\dots,0)^{\top}$ both column vectors of length $M+1$) has a solution $p$ with non-negative components.
That is, one should prove that the first column of $A^{-1}$ is non-negative. For this it is enough to check $det(A)>0$, $det(M_{11})\geq 0$, $det(M_{12})\leq 0$, $det(M_{13})\geq 0$, $\dots$, where $M_{1j}$ is the $(i,j)$-minor of $A$, namely a matrix obtained by deleting its $1$-st row and $j$-th column.
It is enough to prove the following lemma:
Consider a matrix $B=B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)$, where $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_n$, $0\leq q_1<q_2<\dots<q_n$ are
integers, $0 \leq l_1 \leq l_2 \leq \dots \leq l_n \leq n$ are integers, $0 \leq k \leq n$ is an integer, and
$(B_k)_{ij}=
u_{ij}
v_{ij,k}
\frac{\partial^{l_j}}{\partial x^{l_j}}
x^{q_i} \mid_{x=x_j}$, where $u_{ij}=-1$ if $j<i$ and $u_{ij}=1$ otherwise; $v_{ij,k}=-1$ if $i=j$ and $i,j \leq k$.
(Example:
$$ B(1,2,4,7;x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,0,1,1,2;2) 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-x_1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
-x_1^2 & -2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2\\
-x_1^4 & -4x_2^3 & 4x_3^3 & 12x_4^2\\
-x_1^7 & -7x_2^6 & -7x_3^6 & 42x_4^5\\
\end{pmatrix}).
$$
The lemma states that if $l_j > q_j$ for some $j$ then
$$
\det
B=0,
$$
and otherwise
$$
(-1)^k\det
B \geq 0
$$
Also the lemma states that if $k=0$, $l_j \leq q_j$ for each $j$, and for all $j$ such that $x_j=0$ we have $l_j=q_j$, then this determinant is non-zero.
Proof of the lemma:
Denote $j_*=\min\{j: x_j=x_n\}$ and $f[q,l]=\prod_{k=0}^{l-1} (q-k)$. For each $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \dots \leq x_n$ there exists a unique sequence of integers $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that $v_1 = 1$ and for each $j \geq 2$
$v_j=v_{j-1}+1$ if $x_j > x_{j-1}$ and $v_j=v_{j-1}$ otherwise.
We will prove the lemma by induction (with respect to the lexicographical order) in the ordered triple
$(n,-\sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i,\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i)$. Remark that the set of triples we will consider is finite, because if $\sum_{i=1}^n l_i > n q_n$, then $B$ has a column of zeros, so $\det(B)=0$. The base of the induction ($n=1,n=2$) is easy to check.
There are two cases:
Case 1. There exists $j_0 \geq j_*$, $j_0 \leq n-1$ such that $l_{j_0}=l_{j_0+1}$. If $l_{j_0} \geq j_0$, then the $j_0$-th,...,$n$-th column are dependent, so the determinant of $B$ is $0$ and the lemma is proven. So we can assume that $l_{j_0},l_{j_0+1} \leq j_0-1$. Since $j_* \leq j_0$, we have $x_{j_0}=x_{j_0+1}=x_n$.
There are three subcases:
1a) $k<j_0$. Then (since $x_{j_0}=x_{j_0+1}$) after subtracting the $j_0$-th column of $B$ from the $(j_0+1)$-th column the $(j_0+1)$-th column will have only one non-zero element, the element on the position $(j_0+1,j_0+1)$, and it will be equal to $2 \frac{\partial^{l_{j_0+1}}}{\partial x^{l_{j_0+1}}}
x^{q_{j_0+1}} \mid_{x=x_{j_0+1}}=2 f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]x_{q_{j_0+1}}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}} \geq 0$ (if $l_{j_0+1} \leq q_{j_0+1}$, then it is positive).
So by expanding the determinant in the $(j_0+1)$-th line, the sign of
$$
\det
B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)
$$
will be the same as the sign of
$$
\det
B(q_1,\dots,q_{j_0},q_{j_0+2},\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_{j_0},x_{j_0+2},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{j_0},l_{j_0+2},\dots,l_n;k),
$$
so by the induction assumption the latter determinant has the same sign as $(-1)^k$, hence, the former determinant has the same sign as $(-1)^k$, as required.
1b) $k\geq j_0+1$. Then (since $x_{j_0}=x_{j_0+1}$) after subtracting the $j_0$-th column of $B$ from the $(j_0+1)$-th column the $(j_0+1)$-th column will have only one non-zero element, the element on the position $(j_0+1,j_0+1)$, and it will be equal to $-2 \frac{\partial^{l_{j_0+1}}}{\partial x^{l_{j_0+1}}}
x^{q_{j_0+1}} \mid_{x=x_{j_0+1}}=-2 f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]x_{q_{j_0+1}}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}} \leq 0$ (if $l_{j_0+1} \leq q_{j_0+1}$, then it is negative).
So by expanding the determinant in the $(j_0+1)$-th line, the sign of
$$
\det
B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)
$$
will be the same as the sign of
$$
\det
B(q_1,\dots,q_{j_0},q_{j_0+2},\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_{j_0},x_{j_0+2},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{j_0},l_{j_0+2},\dots,l_n;k-1),
$$
so by the induction assumption the latter determinant has the same sign as $(-1)^{k-1}$, hence, the former determinant has the same sign as $(-1)^k$, as required.
1c) $k=j_0$. In particular, $k>0$, so we do not have to care about $\det(B)$ being non-zero. Denote by $B'$ the matrix obtained after subtracting the $j_0$-th column of $B$ from the $(j_0+1)$-th column. Then in the $(j_0+1)$-th column of $B'$ there are only two non-zero elements: $b'_{j_0,j_0+1}=2
f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0+1}]
x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0}-l_{j_0+1}}=2
f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0+1}]
x_{n+1}^{q_{j_0}-l_{j_0+1}}$, $b'_{j_0+1,j_0+1}=2
f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]
x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}}=2
f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]
x_{n+1}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}}$.
Denote (for $k \neq j_0+1$) by $B'_j$ the minor of $B'$ obtained by removing the $j_0$-th row, the $(j_0+1)$-th row, the $j$-th column and the $(j_0+1)$-th column of $B'$. By expanding the determinant of $B$ in the $(j_0+1)$-th column and expanding the two corresponding summands in the $(j_0+1)$-th row and the $j_0$-th row respectively, we obtain (we assume that $l_j\leq q_j$ for all $j$, because otherwise $\det(B)=0$; also recall $l_{j_0}=l_{j_0+1}$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\det(B')&=&
2\sum_{j=1}^{j_0}
(-1)^{j_0+j}
\Bigg(-f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]f[q_{j_0},l_j]x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}}x_{j}^{q_{j_0}-l_j}
\\
&&
\quad
+
f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j}]f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0}]
x_{j}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_j}x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0}-l_{j_0+1}}\Bigg)
\det(B'_j)
\\
&&
+2\sum_{j=j_0+2}^{n}
(-1)^{j_0+j-1}
\Bigg(f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]f[q_{j_0},l_j]x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1}}x_{j}^{q_{j_0}-l_j}
\\
&&
\quad
-
f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j}]f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0}]
x_{j}^{q_{j_0+1}-l_j}x_{j_0+1}^{q_{j_0}-l_{j_0+1}}\Bigg)\det(B'_j)
\end{eqnarray*}
However, since $x_{j_0}=x_{j_0+1}=\dots=x_n$ and since $w_{ij}$ are non-increasing in $j$ and non-decreasing in $i$, the summands in the second sum are either zero or have the same sign as $(-1)^{j_0+j}\det(B'_j)$: indeed, if $l_j>q_{j_0}$, then it is clear, if not, then (recall $l_{j_0}=l_{j_0+1}$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
\frac{f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]f[q_{j_0},l_j]}{f[q_{j_0+1},l_j]f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0}]}
=
\frac{q_{j_0+1}!}{(q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1})!}
\cdot
\frac{q_{j_0}!}{(q_{j_0}-l_{j})!}
\cdot
\frac{(q_{j_0+1}-l_j)!}{q_{j_0+1}!}
\cdot
\frac{(q_{j_0}-l_{j_0})!}{q_{j_0}!}
=
\\
&&
\prod_{i=l_{j_0}}^{l_j-1}
\frac{q_{j_0}-i}{q_{j_0+1}-i} \leq 1,
\end{eqnarray*}
while the summands in the first sum are also either zero or have the same sign as $(-1)^{j_0+j+1}\det(B'_j)$, since $x_j \leq x_{j_0+1}$ for $j \leq j_0$ and
$$
\frac{f[q_{j_0+1},l_{j_0+1}]f[q_{j_0},l_j]}{f[q_{j_0+1},l_j]f[q_{j_0},l_{j_0}]}
=
\frac{(q_{j_0+1}-l_j)!(q_{j_0}-l_{j_0})!}{(q_{j_0+1}-l_{j_0+1})!(q_{j_0}-l_{j})!}
=\prod_{i=l_{j}}^{l_{j_0}-1}
\frac{q_{j_0+1}-i}{q_{j_0}-i} \geq 1.
$$
But for $j \leq j_0$
$$
B'_j
=B(x_1,\dots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\dots,x_{j_0},x_{j_0+2},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{n-2};j-1),
$$
so $\det(B'_j)$ is either $0$ or has the same sign as $(-1)^{j-1}$.
Analogously for $j \geq j_0+2$
$$
B'_j
=B(x_1,\dots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\dots,x_{j_0},x_{j_0+2},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{n-2};j-2),
$$
so $\det(B'_j)$ is either $0$ or has the same sign as $(-1)^{j-2}$.
Overall, all the summands are either $0$ or have the same sign as $(-1)^{j_0}=(-1)^k$, so $(-1)^k\det(B) \geq 0$ as desired.
Case 2. For all $j \geq j_*$, $j\leq n-1$ we have $l_{j+1}>l_{j}$. Again, there are three subcases:
2a) $j_*=1, x_1=0$. In this case if $q_1 > l_1$, then the entries of the first row are zeros, so $\det(B)=0$. If $q_1<l_1$, then again $\det(B)=0$, because the first column contains zeros.
If $q_1=l_1$, and $k=0$, then
$$
\det(B)
=l_1! 
\det(B(q_2,\dots,q_n;x_2,\dots,x_n;l_2,\dots,l_n;0)),
$$
so $(-1)^{k}\det(B) \geq 0$, moreover, if $l_j \leq q_j$ for all $j$ and $l_j=q_j$ if $x_j=0$, then, by the induction assumption, $\det(B) \neq 0$.
If $q_1=l_1$ and $k \geq 1$, then
$$
\det(B)
=-l_1! 
\det(B(q_2,\dots,q_n;x_2,\dots,x_n;l_2,\dots,l_n;k-1)),
$$
so again by the induction assumption $(-1)^k \det(B) \geq 0$.
2b) $j_*=1, x_1 > 0$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
\det(B)
=
\int_{0}^{x_1}
\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;t,x_2,\dots,x_n;l_1+1,\dots,l_n;k))dt
\\
&&
\quad+
\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;0,x_2,\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)),
\end{eqnarray*}
where
$(-1)^k\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;t,x_2,\dots,x_n;l_1+1,\dots,l_n;k)) \geq 0$ (and is non-zero for $k=0, t>0$, when $l_j \leq q_j$ for all $j$) by the induction assumption (remember, we had induction in
$(n,-\sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i,\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i)$) and $(-1)^k\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;0,x_2,\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)) \geq 0$ by the same arguments as in case 2a) (remember, $j_*=1$, so $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n$).
2c) $j_*>1$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
\int_{x_{j_*-1}}^{x_{j_*}}
\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_{j_*-1},t,x_{j_*+1},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{j_*-1},l_{j_*}+1,l_{j_*+1},\dots,l_n;k))dt
\\
&&
\quad+
\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_{j_*-1},x_{j_*-1},x_{j_*+1},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_n;k)),
\end{eqnarray*}
where both the determinants multiplied by $(-1)^k$ are non-negative by the induction assumption (in the first case we increased $\sum_{j=1}^n l_j$, in the second case we decreased $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$). Moreover, if $k=0$, $l_j \leq q_j$ and $l_j=q_j$ for $j$ such that $x_j=0$, then by th induction assumption
for $t>x_{j_*-1}$ we have
$$
\det(B(q_1,\dots,q_n;x_1,\dots,x_{j_*-1},t,x_{j_*+1},\dots,x_n;l_1,\dots,l_{j_*-1},l_{j_*}+1,l_{j_*+1},\dots,l_n;k))
\neq 0,
$$
so $\det(B) \neq 0$.

@IosifPinelis, I think something like $1 = \lim_{M \to \infty} \sum_i p_i^{(M)} = \sum_i \lim_i p_i^{(M)} = \sum_i p_i$ shows that $p_i = \lim_{M \to \infty} p_i^{(M)}$ is a probability measure. Bringing $\lim$ into the sum is possible by dominated convergence theorem with $2^{-i}$ bound from the post.

@IosifPinelis Thank you very much! Now these moments should be fixed.

can you add a bit more details "By passing to a subsequence we can assume that for each ≥1 there exists a limit" ?   Is the concern here that the limit doesn't exists or that the limit is converges to all zero values.

At this stage the concern is that the limit in M may fail to exist (perhaps it still exists, but I have no proof), therefore, we consider a limit not over all M but rather over a suitably narrow subsequence of M. The concern that the limit may fail to correspond to a probability measure is addressed later

I have added some details about it.

Not an answer, but a comment to @ssss nnnn's answer.

Take a sequence $x_i = (i+1)/2 - 1/4$, $i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$ and define $U \sim \sum p_i \delta_{x_i}$, where $p_i$ are some weights we want to determine. Then, the equations
$$
\mathbb{E} U^k \mathbb{1} \left\{ U \geq \frac{k+1}{2} \right\} 
= \mathbb{E} U^k \mathbb{1} \left\{ U < \frac{k+1}{2} \right\},
\quad k = 0, \ldots, M
$$
read
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^k p_i x_i^k = \sum_{i = k+1}^n p_i x_i^k, \quad
k = 0, \ldots, M.
$$
Throwing in one more equation $\sum p_i = 1$, we obtain a system of $M+2$ equations for $n+1$ variables. Letting $M = n-1$, we obtain a system which turns out to be solvable (see @ssss nnnn's proof). The following code in Mathematica solves this system:
x[i_] = (i + 1)/2 - 1/4;
num = 10;
Table[
   Sum[p[i] x[i]^k, {i, 0, k}] 
   == Sum[p[i] x[i]^k, {i, k + 1, num}],
   {k, 0, num - 1}
   ]
  ~ Join ~ {Sum[p[i], {i, 0, num}] == 1}
  ~ Join ~ Table[p[i] >= 0, {i, 0, num}];
% // Solve[#, Table[p[i], {i, 0, num}]] &

Here's the output:

Here are numerical values:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_0 & = 0.5, \\
p_1 & = 0.285454, \\
p_2 & = 0.128578, \\
p_3 & = 0.0517794, \\
p_4 & = 0.0208779, \\
p_5 & = 0.00824254, \\
p_6 & = 0.00315686, \\
p_7 & = 0.00115319, \\
p_8 & = 0.000392655, \\
p_9 & = 0.000121824, \\
p_{10} & = 0.000243685
\end{aligned}
$$
This is an example for $M = 11$. I've tried $M$'s up to $100$, and they all lead to nice solutions.

Here's a plot of $(x_i, p_i)$ for $n = 50$:


Your choice of $x_i$'s is different from the answer. Correct?

@Boby, if you mean ssss nnnn's answer, then I just took middle points of $((k-1)/2, k/2)$ and shifted $k$ by $1$.

Let $k=1$  and $U$ have the density
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1-x/2, &x\in[0,2];\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[U^k 1_{U \ge  \frac{k+1}{2}   }]}{\mathbb{E}[U^k]},     
=
\frac{\mathbb{E}[U 1_{U \ge  1}]}{\mathbb{E}[U]}=\frac{1/3}{2/3}=\frac12.     
\end{align}

This has to be equal to $1/2$ for all $k$. Not just for $k=1$
